# Cordova Console plugin stops working after page load

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I have a Cordova 7.0.1 project which uses [console plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-console/) so that I can `console.log()` on iOS. The plugin works until a redirect e.g.

```
window.location.href = 'index.html';
```

At this point the `console.log()` stops working even though `alert()` still works. It's frustrating because the app is unresponsive at this point (trying to login) and it's a pain debugging with alerts.

In XCode console  I have the following:

```
2017-06-12 15:01:14.828 APP [x:x] Session validated
2017-06-12 15:01:14.835 APP [x:x] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2017-06-12 15:01:15.491 APP [x:x] Finished load of: file:///Users/X/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/X/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/X/APP.app/www/index.html
```

The "Session validated" is console.logged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was CSP declaration as I had `gap:` in the wrong place. This is what I had:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' * data: gap:;">
```

and this is what I replaced it with:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' * data:;">
```